# Map Image Onto Object

Tags: animation, texturing, node-editor, camera, shader-nodes

I am trying to recreate the 2014 Marvel intro in Blender and I am having trouble getting the images of the comic books onto the text. My current solution is to use the camera option from the texture coordinate node which sort of works, but it always follows the camera. In the marvel intro, the comic images are static but still match up as the camera moves. I have included images of what I mean. Thank you in advance[image: Marvel Intro] [image: My Solution]

Answer (score 2):

Of course using the camera's coordinate to project a texture will always follow the camera, it's what it's for.

What you want is a projection from an object, so you can use the object projection, pointed for example to an empty object that you can more, rotate and scale around to your needs.

So create an empty object, give it a good name.
Then in your shader, instead of using the Camera output from your texture coordinates node, use its Object output. And put your empty in the object picker at the bottom of the node.

Comment: This sounds more like what I need, how do I do object projection?

Comment: See my answer edit above